# How can I set the display settings using command line

Tags: display, command-line

I would like to configure the 'Scaled' property of my Macbook Pro display using the command line. How could I do that?

Comment: [display_manager.py](https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/display_manager) works for me. I use this command to get scaled 1920x1080 @60fps on my 4K monitor: `/path/to/display_manager.py res 1920 1080 60`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: This answer is obsolete.**

I have an early 2013 MacBook Pro with Retina Display running OS X 10.8.5 and I've tested [cscreen](http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/) command line utility and it works to change resolution via the command line.  You can download the cscreenIntel.dmg from the link provided. In a terminal use `cscreen -h` to output the internal help information. An example of use: `cscreen -d 32 -x 1680 -y 1050`

BTW As far as I know Intel based versions of OS X do not include a native executable and why I'm pointing you to a third-party utility.

Comment: Did not work for me on os x yosemite 10.10.5 desktop.

Comment: Use [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) for new macOS versions and for multi-monitor setups. More info in my answer below.

Answer (score 25):

To set multi-display resolutions, rotations, mirroring, and positioning via terminal use [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer).

Execute `displayplacer list` to view the possible resolutions for your screen. You'll want to use the ones marked as `scaling:on`

Then, execute a command similar to this to set the config `displayplacer "id:A46D2F5E-487B-CC69-C588-ECFD519016E5 res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0"`

Also available via Homebrew: `brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer`

Comment: your tool works great! also combines very well with ShortCuts on Monterey

Comment: Like a fool, I'd set a display to 75 Hz (why? read my comment from the beginning again). I could access the display when plugged into a different HDMI port, but the ID changed. displayplacer worked for me in that it allowed me to first identify the display id, then run a displayplacer command every 2 seconds in a loop, then plug the display into the HDMI port—after 60 seconds or so, my display reset back to 60 Hz. <3

Comment: This is an awesome tool - thanks for sharing it.   I have a display that my Mac infuriatingly sets to "variable refresh" by default and requires me to reset it once in a while.  With this I can script it whenever I plug in my Mac to run.

Answer (score 17):

Use [screenresolution](https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution) on newer os versions

```
 git clone https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution.git
 cd screenresolution
 make dmg
 ./screenresolution set 1920x1080x32@60
```

csreen did not do any thing for me on os x 10.10.5. These steps worked for me.

Comment: Just FYI that this tool is also now available on Homebrew for a super easy install: `brew install screenresolution` but unfortunately it does not support Retina resolutions.

Comment: screenresolution didn't work well for me with a custom added screen resolution whereas displayplacer did

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE (October, 2023):** Unfortunately, RDM no longer exists on Homebrew :(

See [RDM](https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM/), which can be installed with brew:

`brew install avibrazil-rdm`

It's not well documented, but the same executable that launches the GUI can also be used via the command line, so after installing you can run...

```
/Applications/RDM.app/Contents/MacOS/SetResX --modes
```

...will list all available options, including a "scale" factor for Retina/HiDPI modes. You can then set your desired mode e.g....

```
/Applications/RDM.app/Contents/MacOS/SetResX -w 1680 -h 1050 -s 2.0
```

If you execute the binary via command line without an argument it will list all command line options and then start the GUI. Or you an take a look at the [source](https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM/blob/master/main.mm) directly to see them.

Comment: https://github.com/usr-sse2/RDM is a modern maintained fork, but lacks CLI switching