# How can I set a scaled display resolution from the command-line in macOS Catalina?

Tags: settings, resolution, automation, defaults, setup

I am trying to automate the setup of a Mac running macOS Catalina (10.15.1).

I found this question: [How can I set the display settings using command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173866/how-can-i-set-the-display-settings-using-command-line)
. But none of the answers really explain how I can set this "slightly larger text" setting. I would like to know how to automatically set the configuration in the below screenshot:

[image: Display Scaled Resolution]

Is there a way to do this using the `defaults` command?

Answer (score 7):

I’m not aware of any way to do this via `defaults write` (although it seems like it *should* be possible). I even checked [MacPilot](https://www.koingosw.com/products/macpilot/) which is usually my go-to for hidden defaults.

My suggestion would be to use [display_manager.py](https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/display_manager) which is the best command-line tool that I know of which is being actively developed. It is free, but will require you to figure out the proper settings for your computer.

There’s also [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/) which is a commercial app ($16, I think) but if all you want it for is the initial setup, that might be overkill.

Last but not least, there’s [‎Display Menu](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) which is free, but with a $2 in-app purchase will add AppleScript support, which means you can use it from the command line.

Comment: Worked for me! Using Display Manager (display_manager.py), I created a Workflow using Automator and assigned a keyboard shortcut via System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: (My command: `/path/to/display_manager.py res 1920 1080 60`)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and tried TJ's suggestion display_manager.py
The script worked beautifully and even gave me an option to increase the resolution over what System Prefs/Displays was offering.

I downloaded the whole git to my application directory. Then ran:

```
/Applications/display_manager-stable/display_manager.py show highest
```

I took the results and I ran this:

```
/Applications/display_manager-stable/display_manager.py res 1920 1080
```

I set up a LaunchAgent (using Lingon) with the command above and now when my headless mini restarts I am able to remote in and don't get the default unworkable resolution.

Thanks for this TJ. I had no idea this existed.

Comment: I’m glad it helped you out!