# External screen is black - no signal - macbook pro 16 2019

Tags: display, resolution

I'm using dell dock station to connect external monitor through usb-c.
I have changed the resolution of my second display to 1080i, but this monitor doesnt work anymore on this resolution. All i see is a black screen. How can I change resolution back to 1080p ? Safe mode does not work.

Comment: Can you explain 'safe mode does not work'? Does that mean you can't boot into safe mode? Or that the second display is still black after doing so? Or something else? Stating what happens when you try something makes an issue easier to troubleshoot compared to stating only that something doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot start the pc in safe mode, but the external screen is black.

Comment: Some random thoughts: hardware/connection issue? e.g. bad cable or jack; boot into safe mode with nothing connected and then connect display (if you can't enter safe mode with nothing connected you have another problem); direct connect display (one cable, no dock); if hw not at issue, consider answers on https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/173866/211401;